# 'default' is imported from external module 'rollup' but never used

Tags: angular

I want to run my project by AOT. For test I start quickstart project according to [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html) step by step.
After below command aot folder generated.

```
"node_modules/.bin/ngc" -p tsconfig-aot.json
```

but After rollup command :

```
"node_modules/.bin/rollup"  -c rollup-config.js
```

this error appear :

```
'default' is imported from external module 'rollup' but never used
```

What is problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try commenting out the first line

```
import rollup from 'rollup'
```